# Git - How to fix branch starting at wrong spot?

Tags: git

I have a short git repository. I wanted to create a new branch to check in my updates in progress since they belong to a new project (scalable).

Before creating this branch, the last commit was 7f7ae03. I hadn't committed my new changes yet.

I ran:

```
git checkout -b scalable
```

Then I committed my changes, and pushed my updates.

Now this has done something weird to my repository....

```
7f7ae03  Add custom error page for production environment.  [scalable]
a3d2911  Add custom server response header.  [scalable]
5c5dcb9  Fix whitespace.  [scalable]
ad51b4b  Add tpstatic.js to gitignore.
9cdc074  Made bash scripts executable.
7b537f3  Clean up build scripts for static content.  [scalable]
e05b310  Clean up build scripts for static content.
b458300  Remove zip file from images.  [scalable]
71c121e  Remove zip file from images.
82581b6  Create repository.  [scalable]
46b0470  Create repository.
```

Half of the commits are duplicated in both the master and scalable branch.

The scalable branch begins at "Create repository" instead of 7f7ae03.

Ugh.... Can I fix this, and what did I do wrong to begin with?

EDIT - Could it be related to this command which I ran when checking in?

```
git push --set-upstream origin scalable
```

Comment: This looks like the kind of thing you get when you rebase-and-edit all the commit messages.  An older name (tag or remote branch) saves all the original commits, and the new branch links up all the new commits that rebase made.  `git log --graph --decorate --all` might prove whether this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking to start the branch from different "spot" you need to use git rebase
Something in line with:

```
git rebase topic master
```

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html

I'm curious though how did you get the output that you have provided? You could use the 
`git log --all --oneline --decorate`

or better

`gitk --all`

to see the way the actual history is built right now.